# Changing height and width of Ember.ListView during runtime

Tags: ember.js

According to the [README](https://github.com/emberjs/list-view#changing-height-and-width-of-emberlistview-during-runtime) I should be able to change the width and height of Ember.ListView, but I can't find a way to get it to work.

When I enlarge the dimensions of the `ListView` I expect new items to be created and added to the list, but it doesn't happen.

Does anyone have a working example for this?

UPDATE:

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bazzel/7U2km/) for a code sample.

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: Sorry for that. Sample included now.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it...

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bazzel/7U2km/2/) for updated sample.

I initially defined a `didInsertElement` method on the `ListView` to bind to the window's resize event and update the `ListItem`'s width and height, but this way I apparently overrode the `ListItem`'s own `didInsertElement` method:

```
  App.ListView = Ember.ListView.extend({
      height: 500,
      width: 500,
      elementWidth: 80,
      rowHeight: 20,
      itemViewClass: Ember.ListItemView.extend({
          templateName: 'row_item'
      }),
      adjustLayout: function(w, h) {
          console.log(w, h);
          this.set('width', w);
          this.set('height', h);
      },
      didInsertElement: function() {
          view = this;
          $(window).resize(function() {
              width = $('body').width();
              height = $('body').height();
              view.adjustLayout(width, height);
          });
      }
```

By using `.on('didInsertElement')` the code is working:

```
  App.ListView = Ember.ListView.extend({
      height: 500,
      width: 500,
      elementWidth: 80,
      rowHeight: 20,
      itemViewClass: Ember.ListItemView.extend({
          templateName: 'row_item'
      }),
      adjustLayout: function(w, h) {
          console.log(w, h);
          this.set('width', w);
          this.set('height', h);
      },
      observeResize: function() {
          view = this;
          $(window).resize(function() {
              width = $('body').width();
              height = $('body').height();
              view.adjustLayout(width, height);
          });
      }.on('didInsertElement')
```

Comment: You should wrap the code handling the resize event in `Ember.run` to avoid an autorun.

Comment: Thanks Luke, I converted it into a mixin https://gist.github.com/bazzel/8962240/raw/4cf738cdce5ecbe04c217a2a81aaed5bd1bcc7c7/ember-list-view.js.coffee